# Is it relevant to use the fact table primary key in dimension table?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am designing a database and I am wondering something about primary keys and foreign keys. I have a kind of snowflake database diagram with a fact table and some dimension tables (if I can call it like this). Because of what I am doing, I need to generate a record in my fact table before adding rows in dimension tables and these rows (and tables) are using the primary key of my fact table.

I am reading topics about it and I see that I should use a ID in dimension tables that should be referenced in the fact table (the opposite of what I am doing).

Let me show you a part my diagram for a better understanding :
[image: my diagram]

First of all, sorry, attributes of tables are written in French (I am a French guy, sorry for my bad english btw).
The "MASQUENumMasque" in "dimension" tables reference "NumMasque" of the table "MASQUE", and I use this foreign key as primary key of tables using it.

So, my question is very simple, I am doing right?
If you need more informations or if you are misunderstanding something, tell me!

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong, the data should always be added from the edge of the snowflake model, to the center.

You always have to add a row in the dimension, and then the data in the fact table, pointing to the dimension you just added. Otherwise you will have constraint issues.

Example: You have a fact table: ORDERS (order_id, shop_id) and a dimension table SHOP ( shop_id, shop_name). When loading a new set of data, you will load in the dimension table first, because it will be then referenced in the fact table throught the shop_id key. If you load the fact table first, orders.shop_id will point to nowhere.

So in your case, for table RONCHI for example, you should have columns Ronchi_id. In your table Masque, you should have a column Ronchi_id pointing to the RONCHI's pk.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I forgot one thing, the data in all "dimension tables" (except in LIQUID_EC and COUPON_MASQUE) are always generated after the creation of the MASQUE's id (I need it for tracking in my app). These data could have been all add in the MASQUE table but for readability, I created many little tables instead of one "super-table". Are these little tables dimension tables?